# What does "I can't reach out to call you" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "I can't reach out to call you" mean?
(penultimate line)

> Lyrics:
>   There's a time that I remember,
>   When I did not know no pain
>   When I believed in forever,
>   And everything would stay the same
>   Now my heart feel like December
>   When somebody say your name
>   Because I can't reach out to call you,
>   But I know I will one day, yeah

Comment: I can't take the initiative to make contact with you.

Answer (score 0):

reach [intransitive, transitive] to stretch your hand towards something in order to touch it, pick it up, etc.

- adv./prep. She reached inside her bag for a pen.
  **I reached out to pat the dog.**
  He reached into his pocket and pulled out his phone.
  She reached blindly for the light switch.
  He reached across the table to squeeze her hand.
  reach something + adv./prep. He reached out his hand to touch her.

This is from Oxford Learner's Dictionary

Comment: I am afraid the use in the question is a figurative one, not the literal one which you outline.

Answer (score 0):

It literally means to reach out (extend your arm) *to pick up the phone* and call somebody.

Maroon 5 wrote this song "Memories" as a tribute to their late manager Jordan Feldstein, who died unexpectedly in December 2017 from a pulmonary embolism. The line is basically lamenting that they can't just make a phone call when they miss the person.